# CakePHP: Editing a resource through a REST webservice

Tags: xml, rest, binding, cakephp-2.0

I have a database table called `seasons`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `seasons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

This table is binded to `Season` model and `SeasonsController`. Now I want to implement a REST webservice, following the rules explained [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/REST.html).
I'm facing with success the retrieve of a season (`view($id)` method), the retrieve of the all seasons (`index()` method) and remove of existing season (`delete($id)` method).

The problem happens when I want to create a new season or editing an existing one. I think that the problem is 'cause i mistake the way in which I send the XML request. Does someone know how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

First off it would help to show your controller action. I suspect the issue might be what you are sending to the save method. try outputting $this->data before you do a save and take a look at the structure. Make sure it looks like this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-your-data

If this does not help please post in your question the contents of debug($this->data) and your controller